# (Sum ArrayList) Write the following method that returns the sum of all numbers in an ArrayList: public static double sum(ArrayList<Double> list)

Tags: java, arraylist

Sum `ArrayList` Write the following method that returns the sum of all numbers in an `ArrayList`: `public static double sum(ArrayList<Double> list)`

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
                import java.util.Scanner;

                public class SumArrayList {
                    public static void main(String[] args) {
                        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

                        ArrayList<Double> list = new ArrayList<>(5);
                        System.out.print("Enter any 5 numbers: ");

                        while (in.hasNextDouble()) {
                            list.add(in.nextDouble());
                            }
                            // print list
                            System.out.println("The list is " + list);  
                        }

                        public static double sum (ArrayList<Double>list, double sum) 
                        {

                            double total = 0.0;
                            sum = total;

                            for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++){           
                            sum += list.get(i);         

                            // print sum
                            System.out.println("and " + sum + " is the sum");
                            }

                            return sum;
                        }
                    }
```

Comment: So, what is your question?

Comment: This looks like an interview question to me. We should answer it for you why?

Comment: I'm having trouble getting the correct output. i have to display both the elements of the list (using the ArrayList's toString() method) and also the sum of the elements computed by calling the method sum()..."public static double sum(ArrayList<Double>list)"

Comment: lol @BlakeSeven, not an interview question. Just homework for school. I'm new to coding. Just trying to make something out of myself

Comment: try my answer. Hope you Got the result.. :) @KofiAddiTeacha

Comment: please don't tag java questions with Oracle if it has nothing to do with the Oracle's DBMS.

Comment: @KofiAddiTeacha why do you use an ArrayList when you are getting a specific number of inputs?

Answer (score -4, accepted):

> Try this out ...

```
/* package whatever; // don't place package name! */

import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

/* Name of the class has to be "Main" only if the class is public. */
class SumArrayList 
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
     Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

                    ArrayList<Double> list = new ArrayList<>(5);
                    System.out.print("Enter any 5 numbers: ");

                    while (in.hasNextDouble()) {
                        list.add(in.nextDouble());
                        }
                        // print list
                        System.out.println("The list is " + list);  
                        System.out.println(sum(list));
                    }

                    public static double sum(ArrayList<Double> list) 
                    {

                        double total = 0.0;

                        for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++){           
                        total += list.get(i);
                        }
                          // print sum
                        System.out.println("and " + total + " is the sum");
                        return total;
                    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks bro, it def worked! :)....i've been working on it for hours believe it or not lol

Comment: Would you explain why you feel it is necessary to cast a double to a double?

Comment: just gave it try, wasn't sure that this went against any rules

Comment: Might be a dumb question, but can you explain to me why you felt that putting "throws java.lang.Exception", was necessary? It would work without it. New to the language and was just wondering. @Vikrant

Comment: it is not necessary but this was a mistake because i have copy paste the code and only change the content which is necessary to compile and run it

Comment: removed double as well as `throw` Statement @intboolstring

Answer (score 2):

You can easily do it like this *only one line of code*: (If you use Java 8)

```
public double getSum(List<Double> list) {
    return list.stream().mapToDouble(Double::doubleValue).sum();
}
```

**Usage:**

```
List<Double> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(2.6);
list.add(2.6);
double count = getSum(list);
System.out.println("count = " + count);
```

**And it is the output:**

```
count = 5.2
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are asking how to sum an array list.  To do that, use a **[foreach](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html)** loop to iterate over the entire ArrayList.  I'm not sure why you need `sum` as a parameter.  Lastly, you need to have a space in-between the data type and name.

```
public static double sum (ArrayList<Double> list) {
   double total = 0.0;
   for (double d : list) total+=d;
   return total;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, your feedback is greatly appreciated!

Comment: No problem.  If my answer, or any other answer, helped you out, you an acknowledge that by pressing the checkmark next to it.